# saving jsondict to string value not coming properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

hi I am trying to send a request to server and I am trying to set the value of three labels with reply of the server

my code:-

```
 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"phone=%@",self.tmvp];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
// Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/customer_dataapi.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
//   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
static NSURLSession* sharedSessionMainQueue = nil;
if(!sharedSessionMainQueue){
    sharedSessionMainQueue = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:nil delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
}

[[sharedSessionMainQueue dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
    //  NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
    NSDictionary *temp=jsonDict;
    NSLog(@"Req cust:%@",requestReply);
    NSLog(@"requestReply cust: %@", jsonDict);
    self.names=[temp valueForKey:@"customer_name"];
    [self.namel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.names]];

   // _namel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.names];
    self.emails=[temp valueForKey:@"email"];
    _emaill.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.emails];
    self.dobs=[temp valueForKey:@"dob"];
    _dobl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.dobs];
    self.iname=[temp valueForKey:@"image"];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.names);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.emails);
    NSLog(@"**%@",self.dobs);
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    NSLog(@"imagename:%@",self.iname);
    [self imagedl];
    NSString *valueToSave =[jsonDict valueForKey:@"customer_id"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"custid"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}] resume];
```

first I am sending phone number and I get name, email,dob etc from server

this is my log

```
2017-06-09 14:14:50.006 MenuBar[4127:203694] (
Akshay
)
2017-06-09 14:14:51.503 MenuBar[4127:203694] (
"akshay1318a@yahoo.com"
)
2017-06-09 14:14:51.503 MenuBar[4127:203694] **(
"18-01-1995"
)
2017-06-09 14:14:53.041 MenuBar[4127:203694] requestReply:   [{"customer_id":"111","customer_name":"Akshay","email":"akshay1318a@yahoo.com","phone":"9047038606","dob":"18-01-1995","image":"+919047038606cache.png","level":"0","created_date":"2017-06-07 11:12:55","current_store":"0"}]
2017-06-09 14:14:53.042 MenuBar[4127:203694] imagename:(
"+919047038606cache.png"
)
2017-06-09 14:14:53.041 MenuBar[4127:203694] requestReply: [{"customer_id":"111","customer_name":"Akshay","email":"akshay1318a@yahoo.com","phone":"9047038606","dob":"18-01-1995","image":"+919047038606cache.png","level":"0","created_date":"2017-06-07 11:12:55","current_store":"0"}]
```

this Is my reply but why am I getting a bracket here??? because of that the label shows only bracket!!!in server too there is no bracket added I double checked it!!

Comment: Which bracket are you referring to  is it the box bracket  - '[ ] ' in requestReply ?

Comment: Try adding objectAtIndex: 0, I guess you are getting an Array of objects.    self.names=[[temp valueForKey:@"customer_name"] objectAtIndex: 0];

Comment: `jsonDict` seems to be in fact a `NSArray`, not a `NSDictionary`

Comment: @AravindAR when I save the data of key customer_name I get bracket in the log

Comment: @Coder I don't think it is array of objects and how do u access through key in array

Comment: When I see `[{"customer_id":"111","customer_name":"Akshay","email":"akshay1318a@yahoo.com","phone":"9047038606","dob":"18-01-1995","image":"+919047038606cache.png","level":"0","created_date":"2017-06-07 11:12:55","current_store":"0"}]`, your JSON is cleary an NSArray at top level. A NSArray with only one object which is a Dictionary, but a still NSArray at top level. So `NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error] firstObject];`

Comment: @Akshay try adding objectAtIndex:0,
[{"customer_id":"111","customer_name":"Akshay","email":"akshay1318a@yahoo.com","phone":"9047038606","dob":"18-01-1995","image":"+919047038606cache.png","level":"0","created_date":"2017-06-07 11:12:55","current_store":"0"}]
"[]" -> These braces represents an array amd "{}" -> These curly braces represent an object.
If     self.names=[[temp valueForKey:@"customer_name"] objectAtIndex: 0]; Try this and let me know what result you are getting.

Comment: so how do I access customer id is the first value is @0 not @ 1 and goes on like that??@coder

Comment: @Akshay use for loop to iterate through array of objects and now please don't ask how to use for loop.

Comment: no wat I asked is the values index ll br from 0-watever in the reply order??

Comment: @Coder the json is in dictionary format and I used this method in view controllers which comes before this in same format

Comment: @Coder I am not able to acces through array as u suggested it goes me some error and value doesn't come

Comment: @Coder and you can see at log that request reply is perfect son format bt wen I save it in dictionary something happens have any suggestions??